# CodeMirror render incorrectly when initializing from textarea

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I am trying to initialize a simple CodeMirror editor from textarea but it seem to not render correctly:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/codemirror.css">
    <script src="/Scripts/CodeMirror/codemirror.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/CodeMirror/addon/edit/matchbrackets.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Scripts/CodeMirror/addon/hint/show-hint.css">
    <script src="/Scripts/CodeMirror/addon/hint/show-hint.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/CodeMirror/clike.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/CodeMirror/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
    ....
    <section class="block" id="ValidationFormulaArea" style="display: none;">
        <textarea id="ValidationFormula" name="FORMULA"></textarea>

        <script>
            var editor;
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#ValidationFormulaArea").show(0);

                editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("ValidationFormula"), {
                    lineNumbers: true,
                    matchBrackets: true,
                    lineWrapping: true,
                    mode: "text/javascript"
                });
                editor.setSize(800, 400);
                editor.refresh();
            });
        </script>
    </section>
```

This is what it renders:
[image: Wrong CodeMirror render]

This is what it should render:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't you get any errors in console?

Comment: No error in console

Comment: and all the `js` and `css` files are loading?!

Comment: Yes, no error there neither

Comment: weird, same code is working on my PC right now!

Comment: Don't you have any extra `js code` in this page which may cause any conflict?